# Google login service on android 2.1?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to run some of the google applications like calendar, market, and email but the google login service doesn't work.  The various errors (like NoClassDefFoundError) make it seem like the pieces aren't even installed.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this to work by getting a system image from HTC; however they only have images for 1.5/1.6 so I'm still stuck for 2.0+.  You can find info on how to do this here: http://tech-droid.blogspot.com/2009/11/android-market-on-emulator.html